# Is there any OT equivalent of the 'earthen vessel' concept in 2 Cor. 4:7?

Tags: word-study, history, 2-corinthians

I am looking at the words 'earthen vessel' and was wondering if this concept had a OT equal or not? I am looking for anything in the OT that could be conveying the concept of the treasure (the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ) that is  put in or kept in earthen vessels. I want to know if I am missing some cultural/historical aspect refered to by the OT but that is not that clear maybe.

Comment: Do you mean texts like: 2 Sam 17:28, Prov 26:23, Lev 6:18, 11:33, 14:5, Num 5:17, etc.  How this not simply a search for texts?

Comment: [92 verses Regarding Man being Made of the Dust of the Ground](https://www.openbible.info/topics/god_made_us_from_dirt) . . . .  including Isaiah 64:8 _But now, O LORD, thou art our father; we are the clay, and thou our potter; and we all are the work of thy hand._.

Comment: Thanks for all the Bible texts they shed light on the bigger picture for me, however, I am actually looking for anything in the OT that could be conveying the concept of the treasure (the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ) that is  put in or kept in earthen vessels. @NigelJ your  ref to Is. 64:8 can work as a start for me I suppose, together with texts like Jer. 31:33 and the 'dust of the ground' refs too. I just thought to ask about it here because I wanted to know if I am missing some cultural/historical aspect ref'd by the OT but not that clear maybe.

Comment: Up-voted +1 and answered.

Comment: Gideon's torches inside pitchers [Judges 7] and widow's jar of oil (Jesus) and borrowed vessels (us) [2 Kings 4].

Answer (score 3):

The verse which most stands out to me is Isaiah 52 :7,

> How beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of him that bringeth good tidings, that publisheth peace; that bringeth good tidings of good, that publisheth salvation; that saith unto Zion, Thy God reigneth!

which is reiterated by Paul in Romans 10:15,

> And how shall they preach, except they be sent? as it is written, How beautiful are the feet of them that preach the gospel of peace, and bring glad tidings of good things!

The portion of the body highlighted is that which we least regard and that which is the most lowly, namely the feet, yet how beautiful are those feet seen to be when they convey to us, as you say, 'the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ'.

And . . . . Adam was (directly) made of the dust of the ground yet he prophesied, calling his wife 'Eve' after God had promised a seed from woman that would bruise (from above) the head of the serpent.

Despite his transgression and its consequences, yet Adam preached the gospel to us all, in the naming of his wife 'the mother of all living', that is to say, in prophesy, the mother of him that would be a redeemer, and thence would bring life to all.

Comment: Regarding Adam, the creation story also has this: "So God created man in His own image; in the image of God He created him." (Gen 1:27). The earthen vessel is more than just an earthen vessel.